# webbrowser wrapper

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

Is there any wrapper that would allow me to access and modify raw request data (like the headers, body, cookies directly from the webbrowser object in winforms application using c# ?

Comment: .net has a web browser control, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx

Comment: I know Javascript has that ability.  It can't modify the domain in the url but it can modify the remainder of the URI dynamically.  Selenium project has a JavaScript executor class.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I've seen out there which would let you interrogate what the browser is doing is Fiddler, which has an [API](http://fiddler.wikidot.com/fiddlercore-api).  You might want to check that out, but it's not something that I would personally consider using to ship inside my production software unless I had a real solid requirement for it.

Comment: You'd actually want to use FiddlerCore for this purpose (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/Core/). Asynchronous Pluggable Protocols also would work, but are EXTREMELY difficult to implement properly and fail in myriad ways.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to implement your own [Asynchronous Pluggable Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767743%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). So you'll be able to access and modify requests and then forward them to the destination using, for example, [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) or raw sockets.

Some links you might consider useful to get started with:

- [A Simple protocol to view aspx pages without IIS implemented in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6120/A-Simple-protocol-to-view-aspx-pages-without-IIS-i)
- [Internet Explorer Asynchronous Protocol Library](http://ieasyncprotocol.codeplex.com/)

Although, using Asynchronous Pluggable Protocol in this case still looks like a hack (at least for me).

Answer (score 1):

OK... So I've spent the last 4 days scouring the net for a solid solution to needing functionality like this. Mainly, being able to access the raw outbound request, and the raw inbound response associated with the webBrowser control in .Net. The results are absolutely disappointing. Why is this such a huge deal? Why can't MSFT just fix that control and add properties for the rawRequest and RawResponse? If you look you'll find developers trying to hack their way around this for the last 5-10 years. And nobody has come up with a solution? Really? WTF???

- "WebBrowser.CreateSink Method"

  - Huge can of worms. Going here will break your mind.
- "The most complete C# Webbrowser wrapper control"

  - On Win7, trying to regsrv32 the required old ass ATL DLL from 2006 results in an
    Error.
- "Subclass the WebBrowser control"

  - Won't work to gain access to the actual request/response HTTP packet data.

...sigh